# Mudar diretorio do Download no IE via Macro

Tags: excel-vba, internet-explorer, automatização

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Estou tentando fazer que o Download salve no local indicado no IE Boa VBA. Outra questão que gostaria de ajuda é uma forma de automatizar o botão salvar no download no IE. Alguém poderia me ajudar. Já pesquisei bastante e achei vários fórum, porém testei e não deu certo.

```
NomeDiretorio = "C:\teste\"

For i = 4 To QuantDownload
           
    If Range("S" & i) <> "Baixado" Then
        Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorerMedium
        oBrowser.Navigate Worksheets("Base Concluidos").Cells(i, 18) 'Link para fazer o Download
        NomeSalvar = NomeDiretorio & Worksheets("Base Concluidos").Cells(i, 3)
        Resultado = URLDownloadToFile(0, SiteArquivo, NomeSalvar, 0, 0)
        Range("S" & i) = "Baixado"
        oBrowser.Visible = True
        Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
    Else
        Range("S" & i) = "Baixado"
    End If
        Next i
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)) temos (que aqui é C++, mas provavelmente segue os mesmos parametros):

```
HRESULT URLDownloadToFile(
             LPUNKNOWN            pCaller,
             LPCTSTR              szURL,
             LPCTSTR              szFileName,
  _Reserved_ DWORD                dwReserved,
             LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK lpfnCB
);
```

O `szFileName` tem a seguinte descrição:

> A pointer to a string value containing the name or full path of the
> file to create for the download. If `szFileName` includes a path, the
> target directory must already exist.

Traduzindo:

> Um ponteiro para um valor de string contendo o nome ou caminho
> completo do arquivo a ser criado para download. Se `szFileName` incluir
> um caminho, o diretório de destino já deverá existir.

Então basta adicionar na variavel `NomeSalvar` o caminho de uma pasta existente, exemplo:

```
urldown = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C69MO.png?s=48&g=1"
diretorio = "C:\foobar\"
nomeSalvar = "exemplo.png"
URLDownloadToFile 0, urldown, diretorio & nomeSalvar, 0, 0
```